How to enable Wake-on-LAN on a Raspberry Pi 5?
Is it possible to wake a Raspberry Pi 5 over the LAN using a magic packet / Wake-on-LAN?
I hear a lot of speculation regarding this topic, but I could not find a working tutorial for that. What I want is actually quite simple. In a "normal" windows computer I would enter BIOS and activate the Wake-on-LAN functionality. From this point in time the computer will listen for magic packets on the LAN addressed to its MAC address. While shut off, I could send such a magic packet to that Windows computer (i.e. in Linux with wakeonlan d5:a1:b2:c3:d4:e5) and then the system would turn on. Well, I want to do the exact same thing with my Raspberry Pi 5.

Why? Why not leave the Pi5 powered up? It may still  be using less power than your PC in low power mode monitoring the LAN packets.

"I hear a lot of speculation regarding this topic" -> Really? Do you have any example of this?

No, the hardware does not support this; there is no bios to respond to such signals once the system is shut down, and there is no "sleep" mode (it is either running or not, and once shut down the only way to restart it is by cycling the power to the SoC).
To implement this would require at a minimum a separate ethernet jack connected to a microcontroller of some sort.

Sad to hear Wake on LAN doesn't seem to exist on the Raspberry Pi 5. But good to know that as well. A separate ethernet jack could prove to be the answer. Thank you for your answer. Much appreciated.
